# Replace / restrict non-standard characters in CKEDITOR

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have a CKEDITOR instance (version 4.5.7) into which users input content. This content posts to a database field with the collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

The problem comes when a user pastes text from Word or a similar rich-text editor. Two characters in particular get malformed when they hit the database: `” (&rdquo;)` and `– (&ndash;)`.

I have already set `config.entities` to `false` to prevent the characters from being converted into their HTML equivalents. Now I'm looking for a place where I can intercept the process to find/replace any offending characters. Although the javascript for this sort of thing is easy enough ( `text = text.replace('”', '"')` ), I'm not sure where to put it in order to make this happen. I've tried placing it in various places within the CKEDITOR.htmlParser.basicWriter function, but nothing so far has worked.

This seems like it would be a fairly common problem - is there perhaps a way to set collation on the editor so it matches the database?

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: This is certainly not a common problem because normally you would fix your database ;|. What if the user wants to insert these certain characters?

Comment: @Reinmar You say that like it's a trivial thing. Changing an entire corporation's database collation to fix a comparatively minor issue is not always the "best" solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept plunking away in the basicWriter function until eventually I was surprised to find one place that actually does work. Basically, this is the process I used to solve this problem without editing ckeditor.js

1. Download and open an uncompressed version of the ckeditor.js file.
2. Locate and copy the entire `CKEDITOR.htmlParser.basicWriter` function into the bottom of your config.js file. This basically redefines the function, overriding the real one but allowing us to make customizations to it without necessarily breaking future updates.
3. In the copied function within config.js, locate the getHtml section and customize the `html` variable before it gets returned. Below is a template to help you locate this section

---

```
getHtml: function( reset ) {
var html = this._.output.join( '' );

  // this is where we can replace individual characters or make other 
  // customizations
  html = html.replace('”', '"');
  html = html.replace('–', '-');

  if ( reset )
    this.reset();

  return html;
}
```